# Is Java EE version 8 available in IntelliJ for Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am trying to start a Java project in IntelliJ and I have been asked to do it with Java version 8. I have IntelliJ installed in my computer but I don't see there is a Java version 8 available.

Is there something I need to do in order to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java EE 8 is not yet released, so I assume you mean Java 8 SE (Standard Edition).
For that you'll need to download JDK SE 8 from Oracle and then define SDK as specified [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html):

To configure SDKs at the global (IDE) level:

> 1. Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. ⌘ Semicolon).
> 2. In the left-hand pane, under Platform Settings, click SDKs.
> 3. To add a new SDK, click add and select the desired SDK type.
> 4. In the dialog that opens, select the SDK home directory and click OK. As a result, a new SDK is added to IntelliJ IDEA, and its settings are shown on the SDK page in the right-hand part of the dialog.
> 5. Optionally, edit the SDK name and contents.
> 6. If necessary, add more SDKs as described above.
> 7. Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.

To configure a project SDK

> 1. Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. ⌘ Semicolon).
> 2. In the left-hand pane, under Project Settings, click Project.
> 3. On the page that opens in the right-hand part of the dialog, select the necessary SDK from the Project SDK list.
> 4. If the desired SDK is not present in the list, click New and select the necessary SDK type.
> 5. In the dialog that opens, select the SDK home directory and click OK. As a result, a new SDK is added to IntelliJ IDEA and selected as the project SDK.
> 6. To view or edit the SDK name and contents, click Edit. (The SDK page will open.)
> 7. Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: I thought Java EE and Java SDK where the same. If I run `java -version` I see that I have the Java 8 version installed in my Mac.

Comment: @Alex, IntelliJ is designed to support targeting different java versions for different projects on the same machine. Having Java 8 installed on your Mac doesn't force IntelliJ to compile against it.